# Passing delegate from class to class

Tags: c#, delegates

I have two classes, first:

```
    public class A
    {
        public delegate void Function();

        public string name;
        public Function function;

        public A(string name, Function function)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.function = function;
        }
    }
```

And in second:

```
    public class B
    {
        public delegate void Function();
        List<A> ListA;

        // somewhere in function
        void F()
        {
            ListA[i].function();
        }
        // ---

        public void AddA(string name, Function function)
        {
            ListA.Add(new A(name, function)); // error here
        }
    }
```

It throws these errors:

```
Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'App.B.Function' to 'App.A.Function'
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'App.A.A(string, App.A.Function)' has some invalid arguments
```

How to solve this?

Comment: The answers are good enough.. and also check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71154/C-Delegates-101-A-Practical-Example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have declared `Function` delegate twice, one inside class A and one inside B.
So they're two different types, one called `App.B.Function` and the other called `App.A.Function`.

If you want to share this delegate with both the classes, just declare it once and out of the scope of the classes (i.e. in the assembly scope) e.g.:

```
public delegate void Function();

public class A
{
    public string name;
    ...
}

public class B
{
    List<A> ListA;
    ...
}
```

However, in the `System` namespace exist a certain number of generic delegates that can be used to represent various functions. Have a look at `System.Action<>` and `System.Func<>` types.

Comment: have a look at my question too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76913582/4134215

Answer (score 0):

The reason it happen is that `Function` is declared twice, once in each clases

Comment: I think you meant it's declared once in each class, not twice in both (which would be four total).