# Pass delegate from inside class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, dagger-hilt

> `trackableCollection` is properly injecting in **Fragment** and **Activity** that has @AndroidEntryPoint. Now I need to inject this in CustomView but in constructor

```
@WithFragmentBindings
@AndroidEntryPoint
class TrackableRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, private val trackableCollection: TrackableCollection = TrackableCollection()) : RecyclerView(context, attrs),
    ITrackableCollection by trackableCollection,
    IPresenceAware by trackableCollection {

}
```

As `IPresenceAware` and `ITrackableColleciton` require **trackableCollection**

But I am not able to inject `trackableCollection` to **TrackableRecyclerView**

Is there any way to pass trackableCollection delegate inside class not on Constructor level.

I want to [achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185898/4134215) but not working in my scenario as my class isn't singleton.